# Cannot screen scrape site

Tags: javascript, http, redirect, cookies, screen-scraping

I am trying to screen scrape the contents of the following page (lists all medical specialties) and the contents of the links contained in this page (all the universities that offer training in a given specialty). Here is the main page with all the specialties:
https://services.aamc.org/eras/erasstats/par/index.cfm

The first link on the page is for the specialty Adolescent Medicine (Pediatrics) and the URL is https://services.aamc.org/eras/erasstats/par/display8.cfm?NAV_ROW=PAR&SPEC_CD=321

When I try to directly navigate to the above URL, the server redirects me back to the main page. However, clicking on the link for Adolescent Medicine takes me to the page that I want to access.

I am confused as to why clicking on the link takes me to the correct page, but navigating to the same URL does not. Here are my thoughts:

1. Javascript issues- I disabled JS and I still keep getting redirected to the main page. Moreover, clicking the link in the table still takes me to the correct page.
2. Cookies- I disabled all cookies but still ran into the same problem when trying to access the Adolescent Medicine page using the direct URL. Interestingly, navigating using the table links still works with all cookies disabled.
3. HTTPS- Not really sure how to check if this is causing the problem.

I have spent quite a lot of time looking at the developer's console on Chrome and have not been able to find a reason as to why I cannot access the specialty pages using the direct URL. Any help or guidance will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The key was making sure that the appropriate headers were set. This server apparently requires a valid user agent and the correct referrer set. Once I set the header shown below, it worked!

```
headers = {
   'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
   'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch',
   'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
   'Connection':'keep-alive',
   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36',
   'referer' : 'https://services.aamc.org/eras/erasstats/par/index.cfm'
}
```

Comment: Please accept the answer to make it more visible in searches.